# Bind Apostrophe to be "Control" when used in conjunction with other keys?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to use AHK to bind `'` to be `Control`, but only used in conjunction with other keys besides shift (so that when `'` or `Shift + '` is pressed on its own, it still sends `'` and `"`, respectively)? I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
'::Control
' Up::'
```

My goal is to basically make `'` a control key, while retaining its functionality when pressed alone.

Comment: `Shift+'` is not pressed alone. Please define better your needs.

Comment: @harrymc I edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'::Control                      ; bind ' to be Control

' Up::
    Send, {Ctrl up}             ; release the Control key
    If GetKeyState("Shift","P") ; Shift + '
        Send, "
    else
    If (A_PriorKey = "'")       ; quote was pressed alone
        Send, '
return
```

Answer (score 1):

This script is a bit tricky, so here is what it does.
It assumes that <kbd>Shift</kbd> is always pressed before quote.

- The variable `waskey` marks that an alphabetic key was pressed,
  starting as `0` (false).
- The Loop command sets all alphabetic keys as hotkeys that cause execution of
  label `keypress`, which marks the fact that they were pressed.
- The first rule is for <kbd>'</kbd> down.
  If <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not pressed it sets <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to down.
- The second rule is for <kbd>'</kbd> up.
  It sets <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to up, and if no other key was entered in the meantime
  it issues the <kbd>'</kbd> key.

```
global waskey = 0
global ctrldown = 0

keys = "a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z"
; '|' is used as a delimiter
Loop Parse, keys
   HotKey ~*%A_LoopField%, keypress

keypress:
   waskey = 1
Return

'::        ; quote down
    if !GetKeyState("Shift") {
        waskey = 0
        ctrldown = 1
        Send, {Ctrl down}
        SetTimer, checkPressed, 3
    }
return

' up::     ; quote up
    SetTimer, checkPressed, Off
    unPressCtrl()
return

checkPressed:
    if !GetKeyState("'", "P") {
        SetTimer, checkPressed, Off
        unPressCtrl()
    }
Return

unPressCtrl() {
    if (ctrldown = 1) {
        ctrldown = 0
        Send, {Ctrl up}
        if (waskey = 0)
            Send,'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so close! The problem is, for example, if I press `' + a` (to get the effect of `Control + a` to i.e. select all text in a text field), then when I release the keys I still get a `'` sent to my text field.  Is there to fix this?

Comment: The script was working fine yesterday, but today I'm getting the same results as you. So I made it more deterministic by adding a timer that checks for quote key up. Apparently sometimes the up event is not sent. Funny that AHK is not deterministic.